# Django "with" in template

Tags: django, django-template-filters

I am having trouble with a template that hits the data too many times. I know that I can use "with" for that not to happen, but I do not know how to use "with". 
Here is my code in the template

```
<table class="calendar1">
<tr>
    {% for month, game in one_month %}
        {% for day in month %}

                <td>
            {{ day }} <br />
            {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 1 and day == 1 %}New Year's Day{% endif %}
            {% if forloop.parentloop.first and day == 16 %}Martin Luther King, Jr. Day Observance.{% endif %}
            {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 1 or forloop.parentloop.counter == 11 or forloop.parentloop.counter == 12 %}No game today{% endif %}
            {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 2 and day < 25 %}No game today{% endif %}
            {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 10 and day > 1 %}No game today{% endif %}
                {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 2 %}
                    {% if day == 14 %}Pitchers and catchers report & physicals{% endif %}
                    {% if day == 15 %}Pitchers and catchers first workout{% endif %}
                    {% if day == 17 %}Position players report & physicals{% endif %}
                    {% if day == 18 %}First full squad workout{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}
                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 2 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %} {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 

                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 3 %}
                {% if day == 7 or day == 20 %}No game today{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}

                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 3 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 

                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 4 %}
                {% if day == 2 or day == 10 %}No game today{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}

                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 4 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 5 %}
                {% if day == 1 or day == 18 %}No game today{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}

                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 5 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 6 %}
                {% if day == 5 or day == 19 %}No game today{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}

                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 6 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 7 %}
                {% if day == 10 or day == 11 or day == 12 or day == 13 %}All-stars game break{% endif %}
                {% if day == 6 or day == 20 or day == 17 or day == 24 %}No game today{% endif %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}
                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 7 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 8 %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}
                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 8 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 9 %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}
                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 9 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}{% if forloop.parentloop.counter == 10 %}
                    {% for game in mlbgames %}
                        {% if day == game.date.day and game.date.month == 10 %}
                            {{ game.away_team }} {% if game.away_team == "Angels" %} @ {% else %} vs. {% endif %}  {{ game.home_team }} {{ game.date }} 
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}

            </td>

        {% if forloop.last %}
        </tr>
        {% else %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"7" %}
                </tr><tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The problem is with mlbgames variable that contains all the games for a team of baseball. I am going through a month in my loop and checking if there are games in that month. Then when that loop ends I start the list of games starting from the first game, but I would like to only read the games that are in one month that is == to the month are going through.

Comment: This template is really hard to read. You should try not to pollute your template with a lot of logic. Instead write some python code to build a dictionary of all the things you want to show and pass it to your template as it's context. Especially avoid using the loop counter for control flow.

Comment: That is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the logic to your Python code as mentioned by [trixn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5005177/trixn).
This will probably already fix your issue.
Also, because your template is so complex, it is hard to answer the question based on your scenario. Your explanation below helps.. but it is still a guess.

But, to give answer to how to use the `with` statement in a template:

```
{% with value=assignment %}
   The value: {{ value }}
{% endwith %}
```

The `value` you can use and the `assignment` is the value you want your `value` to hold

I tried to do something what I think might help you, based on values that get hit a lot:

```
{% with game_day=game.date.day %}  
    {{ game_day }} # Now game_day holds the game.date.day
{% endwith %}
{% with game_month=game.date.month %}   
    {{ game_month }}  # Now game_month holds the game.date.month
{% endwith %}
{% with away_team=game.away_team %}  
    {{ away_team }}    # Now away_team holds the game.away_team
{% endwith %}
{% with counter=forloop.parentloop.counter %}   
    {{ counter }} # Also a lot of hits so I included this
{% endwith %}
```

Be sure to use `{% ennwith %}` when ending.
Even better, move all the logic to Python as suggested :)

For more info, check the [django template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/) or jump to the [with section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with)